# Traversing struct in network byte order(Big Endian) --- C Language

Tags: c

I have a series of structs stored in network byte order. I want to retrieve them. How can I do it.

structs of this type are stored in the file. I want to traverse all these structs.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `node.data` is is Big Endian ?

Comment: How large is the int you are talking about?

Comment: Since *data* is an `int` and not an `int*`, I'm not sure what *length* is used for.

Comment: the node.length is given as 16 bits but no information on data...

Comment: *length* is actually an **int**, and this type on most platforms is 4 bytes --> 32 bits. **short int** on the other hand, is 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

#### For single Integer

You can use the following endian changing function: `x` is the integer of which you want to get the reverse endian, `atomicity` is the atomicity of the endian, means the number of bits which are considered as a group. Generally it is 8.

```
unsigned int toggle_endian (unsigned int x, int atomicity)
{
  unsigned int t = 0;
  unsigned int mask, sft_amt;

  switch (atomicity)
    {
    case 8:
      mask = 0xff;
      sft_amt = 8;
      break;

    case 16:
      mask = 0xffff;
      sft_amt = 16;
      break;

    default:
      /* Invalid atomicity value, return 0x0 */
      return 0x0;
    }

  while (x)
    {
      t <<= sft_amt;
      t |= (x & mask);
      x >>= sft_amt;
    }
  return t;
}
```

Also have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

**EDIT1:**

#### For structure/composite data

For a structure or some type of dynamic size which needs to converted to the reverse endian the following function would help:

```
your_type conv_endian (your_type x)
{
  your_type y;
  char *arr = (char *) &x;
  char *arr_conv = (char *) &y;
  int n, i, j;

  n = sizeof (your_type);

  for (i=n-1, j=0; i>=0; i--, j++)
  {
    arr_conv[j] = arr[i];
  }
  return y;
}
```

Test the above function with the below driver:

```
typedef struct _your_type {
  unsigned int a, b;
} your_type;

test conv_endian (your_type x);
int main (void)
{
  your_type x, y;
  x.a = 0x12ab34cd;
  x.b = 0x98ef76af;
  y = conv_endian (x);
  printf ("\n%x %x", x.a, x.b);
  printf ("\n%x %x", y.a, y.b);
  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

#### For any structure

```
/* x: base address of the memory
 * n: length of the memory
 */
void reverse_endian (void *x, int n)
{
  char *arr_conv, *arr, t;

  arr = arr_conv = (char *) x;
  arr += (n-1);

  n/=2;

  while (n)
  {
    t = *arr_conv;
    *arr_conv = *arr;
    *arr = t;

    n--;
    arr_conv++;
    arr--;
  }
}
```

Check this post [Swapping endiannes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232671/swapping-endiannes-in-c)

Comment: You just swapped the bytes, right? means you converted the value from one endian to other. So first I need to find the size of the struct and based on that I need to reverse it.. Is that what you are trying to explain?

Comment: whatever data you need to wrap you need to send it into the function's `x` parameter. Please test it before implementation.

Comment: @rohit: This is a Question Answer site. Please read : [http://stackoverflow.com/about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [http://stackoverflow.com/faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know how to use this site and what this site is all about.

Comment: @rohit: if your problem is solved then please accept the answer of the person who helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `int` values are in fact 4 bytes long, then you can use code similar to this:

```
enum { STRUCT_SIZE = 8 };

void data_reader(FILE *fp)
{
    char buffer[STRUCT_SIZE];
    struct node data;

    while ((fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp) == 1)
    {
        unpack_struct(buffer, &data);
        ...stash the unpacked structure...
    }
}

void unpack_struct(const char buffer[STRUCT_SIZE], struct node *data)
{
    load_int4(&buffer[0], &data->data);
    load_int4(&buffer[4], &data->length);
}

void load_int4(const char *data, int *value)
{
    *value = ((((data[0] << 8 | data[1]) << 8) | data[2]) << 8) | data[3];
}
```

There's more than one way to write `load_int4()`, but that's compact enough and clear enough for most purposes.  It could be made into a macro, or (better) an inline function.

Equally, you can extend this to cover more types: `load_int2()`, `load_int8()`, maybe unsigned alternatives, etc.  You might consider whether plain `int` is the best type to use in the structure; it might be better to use the types from `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` such as `int32_t`.

Comment: Can I use builtin function ntohl() instead of load_int4 ?

Comment: @rohith: you may use any function you like that has equivalent functionality.  If `ntohl()` does the job, you may use it.  However, its signature is `uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong)`; it does a different job from `load_int4()`.  There are ways you could make things work so that you could use `ntohl()`, but I'm not certain they're worth the trouble.  The code would be somewhat different in organization.

Comment: @rohith: it may also be that I'm dealing with a different question from what you're asking; I'm assuming that the `FILE *` is a channel from which you read the data.  (It would not be very different if it was a file descriptor instead of a file stream.)  The data was placed there in network order; you want to get the data out of the channel into program variables.  If, for some reason, you've already got the data into the program, then you face a different set of issues and `ntohl()` might well be more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would really like to see what you have written so far. But meanwhile, I'll assume you can convert between endianness (if you don't, Google can provide a ton of tutorials). This leaves you with the task of reading a struct from a file. Right now is not clear to me what *length* does in your struct. Right now it seems it's just meant to be regular data, so to read a struct you would do something like the following:

```
struct node 
{ 
  int data; 
  int length; 
};

FILE* pFile = fopen( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(struct node), pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

// 1- perform the conversion from one endianness to another
// 2- convert from char* to node*
node* tmp_struct = (node*)buffer;

printf("data: %d\n", tmp_struct->data);
printf("length: %d\n", tmp_struct->length);

fclose (pFile);
free (buffer);
```

This code hasn't been tested but it illustrates the tasks of the application. The example above reads only the first available struct in the file. I'll leave the rest as homework for you.