# Swapping endiannes in C

Tags: c, endianness

I have this string

```
c1eb044f0708015b267913fc4dff5aabe3dd4a97f10f7ba935cd360000000000
```

How does one swap it so it becomes

```
000000000036cd35a97b0ff1974adde3ab5aff4dfc1379265b0108074f04ebc1
```

Those two are basically examples, but that is what i need to do, but not know how as i have very little knowledge of C.

The above two strings are actually unsigned char[] in the C program

P.S
Don't think i didn't go through google. I did, but i found very little of what i needed so every attempt to do that failed.

Comment: this is not endian. this is a string reversal. google "reverse string c" and you will get a lot of results.

Comment: This looks like homework. Should it be so tagged?  :)

Comment: It depends on what types of data that string represents.  If it's a sequence of bytes, then there is no notion of endianness.  But if it's a sequence of 16-, 32-, 64-bit values or any combination, then it would matter.

Comment: It's not homework. 
@ madmik3. It is. Try to do a simple reverse the text and you will notice how the characters dont match.

Comment: Swap the `i`th byte (two characters) with the `n - i`th byte. As Jeff pointed out, this makes very little sense (as anything except a thought exercise/homework anyway).

Comment: @pick: The problem is i don't understand these bit operators at all...

Comment: @Micah Hainline: No. The 'homework' tag doesn't mean anything. Nobody will make searches like '[homework] apples oranges'. In my opinion, this tag should be removed from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @pickypg: You mean the `n-i+1`th byte :) (or, if we're using 0-based and i starts at 0, `n-i-1`)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: Then they can better not add the 'homework' tag, because then you get full answers...

Comment: @Blue You're right (`n - i - 1` in 0 based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this; probably not perfect but gives you the idea.  You'll want appropriate error checking, initialization of your buffer, etc.

**Edit:** I made an assumption I shouldn't have, possibly.  I interpreted your string as hex representations of bytes, so I took `c1` as an `unsigned char` and switched it with `00`, for example.  If your string is actually lowercase c, the number 1, etc., then Micah's answer is what you want, not mine.

```
void reverse_string(unsigned char *buf, int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char temp;

    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[length - i - 1];
        buf[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2) {
    myNewStr[size - i - 2] = myStr[i];
    myNewStr[size - i - 1] = myStr[i + 1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want, include at least *string.h* and *stdlib.h.*

```
unsigned char *stringrev(const unsigned char *s) {
  size_t n = strlen((const char *)s);
  unsigned char *r = malloc(n + 1);

  if (r != NULL && !(n & 1)) {
    const unsigned char *fp = s;
    unsigned char *rp = r + n;

    for(*rp = '\0'; n > 1; n -= 2) {
        *--rp = fp[1];
        *--rp = fp[0];
        fp += 2;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight alternative to Micah's answer. I assume that the size is precalculated and even, and check that it's greater than 0 because `s-2` is potentially UB. I modify the string in-place just for variety.

```
static inline void swap_uchar(unsigned char *l, unsigned char *r) {
    unsigned char tmp = *l;
    *l = *r;
    *r = tmp;
}

void reverse_pairs(unsigned char *s, size_t size) {
    if (size > 0) {
        for (unsigned char *l=s, *r=s+size-2; l < r; l += 2, r -= 2) {
            swap_uchar(l, r);
            swap_uchar(l+1, r+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string: `"12ab\0"` then the reverse endian of this string would be `"\0ba21"` .

If you have a numeric: `0x12ab` then the reverse endian of this numeric would be `0xab12` .

Which one do you want.

Here is a function for converting between endian, which will handle the passed argument as a block of memory and change the endian.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct _test {
  unsigned int a, b;
} test;

/* x: base address of the memory
 * n: length of the memory
 */
void reverse_endian (void *x, int n)
{
  char *arr_conv, *arr, t;

  arr = arr_conv = (char *) x;
  arr += (n-1);

  n/=2;

  while (n)
  {
    t = *arr_conv;
    *arr_conv = *arr;
    *arr = t;

    n--;
    arr_conv++;
    arr--;
  }
}


int main (void)
{
  char str1[] = "c1eb044f0708015b267913fc4dff5aabe3dd4a97f10f7ba935cd360000000000";
  char str2[] = "hellio";
  /* Assigns the str1 as hex values */
  unsigned char str3[] = {0xc1, 0xeb, 0x04, 0x4f, 0x07, 0x08, 0x01, 0x5b, 0x26, 0x79, 0x13, 0xfc, 0x4d, 0xff, 0x5a, 0xab, 0xe3, 0xdd, 0x4a, 0x97, 0xf1, 0x0f, 0x7b, 0xa9, 0x35, 0xcd, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  test x;
  char q = 0x12;
  int v = 0x1234abcd;
  int i, n;

  x.a = 0x12ab34cd;
  x.b = 0x98ef76af;

  printf ("\nNormal : x.a = %x x.b = %x", x.a, x.b);
  reverse_endian (&x, sizeof (x));
  printf ("\nReverse: x.a = %x x.b = %x", x.a, x.b);

  printf ("\nNormal : q = %x", q);
  reverse_endian (&q, sizeof (q));
  printf ("\nReverse: q = %x", q);

  printf ("\nNormal : q = %x", v);
  reverse_endian (&v, sizeof (v));
  printf ("\nReverse: q = %x", v);

  printf ("\nNormal : str1 = %s", str1);
/* minus 1 to avoid the trailing nul character */
  reverse_endian (str1, sizeof (str1) - 1);
  printf ("\nReverse: str1 = %s", str1);

  printf ("\nNormal : str2 = %s", str2);
/* minus 1 to avoid the trailing nul character */
  reverse_endian (str2, sizeof (str2) - 1);
  printf ("\nReverse: str2 = %s", str2);

  printf ("\nNormal : str3 = ");
  n = sizeof (str3);
  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf ("%x", (str3[i]>>4)&0x0f);
    printf ("%x", str3[i]&0x0f);
  }
  reverse_endian (str3, sizeof (str3));
  printf ("\nReversed: str3 = ");
  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf ("%x", (str3[i]>>4)&0x0f);
    printf ("%x", str3[i]&0x0f);
  }

  printf ("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Normal : x.a = 12ab34cd x.b = 98ef76af
Reverse: x.a = af76ef98 x.b = cd34ab12
Normal : q = 12
Reverse: q = 12
Normal : q = 1234abcd
Reverse: q = cdab3412
Normal : str1 = c1eb044f0708015b267913fc4dff5aabe3dd4a97f10f7ba935cd360000000000
Reverse: str1 = 000000000063dc539ab7f01f79a4dd3ebaa5ffd4cf319762b5108070f440be1c
Normal : str2 = hellio
Reverse: str2 = oilleh
Normal : str3 = c1eb044f0708015b267913fc4dff5aabe3dd4a97f10f7ba935cd360000000000
Reversed: str3 = 000000000036cd35a97b0ff1974adde3ab5aff4dfc1379265b0108074f04ebc1
```

Note that the strings `str1`, `str2` are simply reversed, because each character of the string is one byte. The same character string you have provided is represented as byte string in `str3`. Its hex values are shown as output. The operations for all the data are identical, as it is only concerned to memory byte ordering.